# C#: How to check if I can read and/or delete a directory

Tags: c#, access-control, directory

I loop through a bunch of directories recursively. Some of them (like *D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-20*) give me a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. I suppose that I can just catch it and move on, but I would rather figure that out in advance.

So, when I have a `DirectoryInfo` object. How can I see if I am allowed to `GetDirectories()` and possibly `Delete()` it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you intend to delete it, try to delete it and then proceed (handling the exception as appropriate).

If you perform a check-and-then-delete-if-should-be-able-to-delete there is the chance of a race condition on the filesystem, however slight. This applies to most all file/directory access operations. Most filesystem operations are designed to be atomic and moving this logic into user code conflicts this atomicity and one would *still* need to handle a possible exception being raised.

Comment: Agreed...plus, checking delete rights on every folder before deleting seems like it would be a big performance hit versus handling the occasional exception (provided no delete permissions is the exception instead of the rule).

Comment: Thing is that I first get directories, and then call the same method on all of those. Then I check if the directory is empty, and if it is I try to delete it. In other words, it is first a read, and then later maybe a delete depending on if the directory is still empty or not.

Comment: @pjabbott, I guess that is a good point. Maybe I'll just handle the exception instead. Something which I probably should either way...

Answer (score 5):

I built following code. Please, see if it helps:

```
//using System.IO;
//using System.Security.AccessControl;
//using System.Security.Principal;

string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(
    Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\.."), 
    "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string directory in directories)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    DirectorySecurity security = info.GetAccessControl();
    Console.WriteLine(info.FullName);
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in 
             security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tIdentityReference = {0}", rule.IdentityReference);
        Console.WriteLine("\tInheritanceFlags  = {0}", rule.InheritanceFlags );
        Console.WriteLine("\tPropagationFlags  = {0}", rule.PropagationFlags );
        Console.WriteLine("\tAccessControlType = {0}", rule.AccessControlType);
        Console.WriteLine("\tFileSystemRights  = {0}", rule.FileSystemRights );
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
D:\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\bin
    IdentityReference = BUILTIN\Administrators
    InheritanceFlags  = ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
    PropagationFlags  = None
    AccessControlType = Allow
    FileSystemRights  = FullControl
```

Note that `IdentityReference` and `FileSystemRights` properties; probably you should test your current ACL against them before trying to delete a directory.

Comment: I do not work with windows security a lot (ok, not at all), so could you elaborate on how i can check whether the current user (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()) can delete files from a directory? Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to write your own `GetDirectories()` method; that recursivly gets the ones inside of it.

[This Microsoft Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) has a good article on how to do it, with a bit of work you can clean it up to use Generic Lists and make it fit your solution.

Simply put, System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories() will fail every time it gets one of those exceptions.

Code roughly like this (copied from above) should get you started

```
    List<String> directories = new List<String>();
    void DirSearch(string sDir) 
    {
        try 
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
            {
                //foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
                //{
                //    
                //}
                // use this to search for files recursivly.
                directories.Add(d);
                DirSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Once you have your list of directories, you can then perform operations on them, with some mods the above method should ensure you have read permissions on anything in the list.